# 'Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function' Error: While building Federated Averaging Process

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras, tensorflow-federated

I am getting 'Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function' error while trying to build my federated averaging process. I have tried all remedies for compatibility of v1 & v2 given in other other similar stack overflow questions, viz., using tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution() , tf.disable_v2_behaviour(), etc. But, nothing worked. My revelvant code extract is given below. My complete code in a Python notebook is given here https://gist.github.com/aksingh2411/60796ee58c88e0c3f074c8909b17b5a1.

```
#Making a Tensorflow Model
from tensorflow import keras

def create_keras_model():
 return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  hub.KerasLayer(encoder, input_shape=[],dtype=tf.string,trainable=True),
  keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
  keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'),
])

def model_fn():
# We _must_ create a new model here, and _not_ capture it from an external
# scope. TFF will call this within different graph contexts.
keras_model = create_keras_model()
return tff.learning.from_keras_model(
  keras_model,
  input_spec=preprocessed_example_dataset.element_spec,
  loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(),
  metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()])

# Building the Federated Averaging Process
iterative_process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(
model_fn,
client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-68fa27e65b7e> in <module>()
  3     model_fn,
  4     client_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.02),
  -->5     server_optimizer_fn=lambda: tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=1.0))

 9 frames
 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/autograph/impl/api.py in 
wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
263       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
264         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 265           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
266         else:
267           raise

RuntimeError: in user code:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py:222 call  *
    result = f()
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/saved_model/load.py:486 _call_attribute  **
    return instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:580 __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py:618 _call
    results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:2420 __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:1665 _filtered_call
    self.captured_inputs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:1760 _call_flat
    flat_outputs = forward_function.call(ctx, args_with_tangents)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py:627 call
    executor_type=executor_type)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py:1148 partitioned_call
    args = [ops.convert_to_tensor(x) for x in args]
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py:1148 <listcomp>
    args = [ops.convert_to_tensor(x) for x in args]
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:1307 convert_to_tensor
    raise RuntimeError("Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without "

RuntimeError: Attempting to capture an EagerTensor without building a function.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like tensors are being created outside and later being captured by `model_fn`. The comment inside `model_fn()` is related here:

```py
# We _must_ create a new model here, and _not_ capture it from an external scope. TFF 
# will call this within different graph contexts.
```

TensorFlow doesn't allow referencing tensors created in different graphs (or `tf.function`), so we must construct everything that will be referenced insdie `model_fn()` (or within the inner `create_keras_model()`).

To go about finding where the errant tensor is being created it can be useful to examine the stack trace. The first line of the stack trace seems to indicate **tensorflow_hub**:

```py
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_hub/keras_layer.py:222 call  *
    result = f()
```

The place in the source code that immediately appears to use TF Hub is the first layer of the `tf.kears.Sequential` construction:

```py
def create_keras_model():
  return tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    hub.KerasLayer(encoder, input_shape=[],dtype=tf.string,trainable=True),
    …
```

It seems like this function may be "closing over" or "capturing" the value for `encoder`, which in turn may have tensors that were created in different contexts. Is it possible to move the construction of `encoder` to *inside* `create_keras_model()`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have taken encoder() function inside the create_keras_model(). The earlier error has now cleared. However, I am getting a new error when running the first round of training. state, metrics = iterative_process.next(state, federated_train_data). The error is        UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported [[{{node StatefulPartitionedCall_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/Cast_1}}]] [[StatefulPartitionedCall_1]] [[import/StatefulPartitionedCall_3/ReduceDataset [Op:__inference_wrapped_function_65986] Function call stack:wrapped_function -> wrapped_function

Comment: The new error is coming from TensorFlow core (before TensorFlow Federated is involved), so it maybe useful to open a new question tagged with TF hub and TF. That said, it looks like the `dtype=tf.string` maybe problematic? It's hard to debug without knowing more about what `encoder()` is doing or how the datasets passed to `next()` are constructed. It may be that somewhere is receiving `tf.float` data (possibly the `hub.KerasLayers`), but has  to be constructed to expected `tf.string` dtypes.

Comment: I have raised a new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62786889/error-while-encoding-with-hub-keraslayer-while-using-tff. Your help and comments would be appreciated. Thanks.